# Ember.js - Why wont .property() fire but .observes() does

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm playing around with some [Ember Sortable bits](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html) and I have a simple list that I'm sorting just fine. I'd like to also filter it by what I type into the input box.

However, the `.property()` observer I first tried never works. But if I change `.property()` to `.observes()` it works fine.

Why?

Heres [my JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/direzu/2/edit)

Comment: `observes` is synchronous and immediate (now), and `property` is lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, function with .observes('abcd') is called whenever the property 'abcd' changes. function with .property('abcd') is a property in itself and needs to be called explicity in the templates. Then whenever 'abcd' changes, the property also changes accordingly.

For example, in your case, if {{sortData}} is called in the html templates, then whenever filteredData changes, the corresponding changes are output in the console log.

Here is the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yanokujeyehu/1/edit) demo.

I have changed the code above to just demo to you how .property() works. For your example, sortData returns no value and is not suited as a .property(). It makes more sense to leave it as .observes()